# "use" builtin classes without an alias

Tags: php, namespaces

I see the following code at the top of one of the PHP files im working on.

```
use DateTime, DateTimeZone;
```

Is this code useless or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the file in question is under its own namespace.

It's used so that you don't have to use `\DateTime` in the code.

Comment: Thanks this was the most concise answer.

Answer (score 2):

Developers do this to make their lives a bit easier and the code a bit more pretty when working inside namespaces. To explain a bit...

You use namespaces to prevent possible naming collisions with different frameworks. Let's say you work inside a namespace 'MyApp'. Now, because you are now inside of a namespace, you cannot use php's native classes without the leading '\' because those native classes live in the [global namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) ( which you identify with '\' before class names ). So if you ever need to use the native DateTime class, you would have to use it with the backslash - \DateTime.

But you can also import things from other namespaces if you know you are going to use them - by using the **use** keyword after your namespace declaration. That way, you do not have to use the full namespaced name of a class you are going to use, but only the class name itself as you are used to from working without namespaces.

Saying

```
namespace MyApp;
use DateTime;
```

Will import the \DateTime class into your MyApp namespace, effectively allowing you to just use DateTime in your code.

You should read more about namespaces on [php's website](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). There's more stuff to be told about namespaces than I can possibly cover in this post.

Comment: I already knew what namespaces were, I just wasn't sure why we needed to do "use DateTime" without any prefix path. But gave you upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This code is because it is likely that the source file will also contain a `namespace` definition. This means that you can access built-in classes only with a leading `\` after that `namespace` definition:

like:

```
namespace Foo;

$dt = new \DateTime();
```

To prevent themselves from typing the leading `\` or in order to make it possible to include some legacy code, they aliased the classes